# Лучший способ управления таббаром

Tags: android, архитектура, actionbar, android-toolbar

Доброго времени суток.
Привычной для меня архитектурой (UI) приложения является:

- Одно или несколько, но как можно меньше `Activity` c `ActionBar`
- Множество фрагментов

И каждый раз я сталкиваюсь с проблемой управления функциональностью `ActionBar` - на одном фрагменте мы отображаем одни иконки с таким-то функционалом, при другом активном фрагменте мы какую ту часть иконок убираем и отображаем другие. Соотвественно приходится всем этим делом управлять через пару методов в `Activity` которые со временем становятся монстроидальными, так как фрагментов и условий отображения тех или иных элементов в `ActionBar` все больше и больше.

Может кто либо посоветовать хороший пример, так называемый best practice, где ярко и четко отображается удобный способ управления `ActionBar` и его функционалом в моем случае?

Comment: Что мешает управлять меню или каким либо другим контентом внутри каждого фрагмента? У фрагментов есть такие же обработчики, как и у активности например `public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu, MenuInflater)`, а городить перестановки элементов в активности это очень кривое решение

Comment: так как это решение мне показалось кривым я и задал вопрос. Я правильно понимаю, что вы предлагаете в каждом фрагменте (то есть из Activity убрать логику работы вообще) переопределять метод onCreateOptionsMenu для своих нужд так же как и создать свой menu_<fragment_name>.xml?

Comment: Да, именно так, все внутри каждого контекста для своих нужд

Comment: Если вы юзаете кучу фрагментов внутри активности, то для активности остается только инициализация, переключение фрагментов и общение между фрагментами

Comment: Попробую следовать вашей логике. Оформите ответ, как проверю как это работает обязательно отмечу

Comment: Здесь нужно не пробовать решение @georgehardcore, а безусловно использовать, как правильное и логичное при формировании собственного меню в фрагменте.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не нужно при использовании `Fragment`'ов переносить логику управления меню в активность, что порождает кучу логики изменения visibility элементов меню, не говоря о кастомных layout или `ActionMode`, при фрагментах <10 это будет еще не так заметно, а если их будет 100?

Вместо этого Вам нужно создавать свое меню у каждого фрагмента со своей логикой обработки событий, активности остается только инициализация, переключение фрагментов и общение между фрагментами

Класс `Fragment` содержит полноценное API для работы с меню:

1. `void setHasOptionsMenu(bollean)` включить меню для данного фрагмента
2. `void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu, MenuInflater)` инициализация меню
3. `boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem)` обработка нажатия без использования `Toolbar`, для `Toolbar` используется callback `Toolbar.OnMenuItemClickListener`
4. для вызова метода инициализации из пункта 2), чтобы обновить состояние меню есть метод `supportInvalidateOptionsMenu()` если используется Support Library, если нет, то `invalidateOptionsMenu()` этот метод содержит класс Activity, поэтому вызов должен происходить примерно так: `getActivity().supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();`